# laravel 8 doesnt get data from ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables, laravel-8

[image]

i keep failing to get the multiple checkbox's values in server, always giving me null every time i dump.

[image]

however i can get those values in console, but i want them to be in the server and unfortunately i dont know exacly how to do that. i tried many ways from this site, yotube, etc. but i keep fail. im still learning tho, hope you can understand my explanation, thank you so much for your time to be in this post

this is the form code

```
<form action="/kelompok-asistensi/asisten/{{$user->id}}/peserta" method="POST" id="formtambahpeserta">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modalLgContent">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="asisten-pendamping">Asisten</div>
                            <div class="nama-asisten">{{$asisten->nama}}</div>
                        </div>
                        @if($peserta_all->count() > 0)
                        <div class="pilih">
                            Pilih peserta untuk ditambah ke kelompok ini
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="alert alert-success collapse" role="alert" id="success-alerts">
                                <span class="success-text"></span>
                            </div>
                            @if($peserta_all->count() > 0)
                            <table class="table pilih-peserta" cellspacing="0" id="example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="col-1"></th>
                                        <th class="col-2">No</th>
                                        <th class="col-3">NPM</th>
                                        <th class="col-4">Nama</th>
                                        <th class="col-5">Angkatan</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($peserta_all as $data)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="check-box" id="chk" value="{{ $data->id }}"></td>
                                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->npm }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->nama }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $data->id_angkatan }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            @else
                            <div class="status">
                                <a>Tidak ada peserta untuk dapat ditambah</a>
                            </div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <input name="id_asisten" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_asisten" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $user->id }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: rgb(71, 71, 71);">Close</button>
                        @if($peserta->count() > 0)
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="habc">Tambah</button>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </form>
```

this is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "pagingType": "numbers",
    "pageLength": 15,
    "info":     false,
    language: {
    searchPlaceholder: "cari",
    search: "",
    },
    columnDefs: [
    { "targets": 0, "sortable":false },
    { "targets": 1 },
    { "targets": 2, "sortable":false },
    { "targets": 3, "sortable":false },
    { "targets": 4 }
    ]
});

$("#formtambahpeserta").on('submit', function(e){
    let checkbox_terpilih = $('#example tbody .checkbox:checked');
    let semua_npm = [];
    $.each(checkbox_terpilih, function(i, elm) {
        semua_npm.push(elm.value);
    });
    console.log(semua_npm);
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        method:'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {npm:semua_npm},
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:function(res){
            table.ajax.reload(null, false);
            $("#modaltambahpeserta").modal('hide');
        }
    });
}); });
```

and this is the controller

```
    public function peserta_tambah(Request $request, User $user)
{
    dd($request->npm);
    Peserta::where('id_asisten', $user->id)->whereIn('id', $request->npm)->update(['id_asisten' => $user->id]);
    return response()->json(true);
}
```

edit:

this is the route

```
Route::post('/kelompok-asistensi/asisten/{user:id}/peserta', [KelompokController::class, 'peserta_tambah']);
```

this is what i get from dd($request->all());
[image]

so i checked multiple checkbox and there is only one data, and it seems there is no array in ajax because it cant be seen in the request

and this is alert of 'semua_npm' variable before ajax call which is an array
[image]

the network tab
[image]

Comment: Try to `Log::info($request->npm);` instead of dumping because you are using an ajax request.

Comment: it gives me error like this TypeError
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings(): Argument #1 ($bindings) must be of type array, null given, called in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove  `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"` from ajax.So it uses default content type .

Aslo if you are not setting csrf token globally in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr('action'),
            method:'post',
           
            data: {npm:semua_npm,  _token: @json(csrf_token())},
      
            success:function(res){

            }
        });
```

then in your server side you can access like this

```
$request['npm']
```

Updated

```
$("#formtambahpeserta").on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    let checkbox_terpilih = $('#example tbody .checkbox:checked');
    let semua_npm = [];
    $.each(checkbox_terpilih, function(i, elm) {
        semua_npm.push(elm.value);
    });
    console.log(semua_npm);
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        method:'post',
        data: {npm:semua_npm,  _token: @json(csrf_token())},
        
        success:function(res){
            table.ajax.reload(null, false);
            $("#modaltambahpeserta").modal('hide');
        }
    });
}); });
```

[image]

[image]

Your controller method should be

```
public function peserta_tambah(Request $request, User $user)
    {
       
        Peserta::where('id_asisten', $user->id)->whereIn('id', $request['npm'])->update(['id_asisten' => $user->id]);
        return response()->json(true);
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately it still gives me null

Comment: console.log(semua_npm) .check what you get

Comment: if you get value in console.log then check dd($request->all())

Comment: yes, i edited the post, you can see my route, the console.log(semua_npm) give me an array which i want it to be in the server but the dd($request->all()) gives null, no idea why

Comment: i think ajax is not calling instead its directly posting normal .you can see request all has check-box.  try alert before ajax call and i have updated post

Comment: i updated again, you can see the alert before ajax call

Comment: have you tried my latest updated ajax code

Comment: okay.once you check network tab console.what you are sending and getting in that request.since without live code difficult to predict form my side.but this help us to get some idea

Comment: im not sure what network tab are you talking, but you can see i updated my post

Comment: browser developer  network tab .press F12

Comment: you can see its not actually sending request .there is no request /kelompok-asistensi/asisten

Comment: so what's wrong? the url: inside ajax call maybe?

Comment: as code looks good .any way try consoling console.log($(this).attr('action')) .

Comment: it gives me this, nothing wrong right? its same as in the route /kelompok-asistensi/asisten/48/peserta

Comment: @yes that correct.but difficult to debug.if you are able to share code in git then i can look inot it or else bit difficult form my side

Comment: https://github.com/mikkelnf/administrasi-lppc, there it is, you can download the zip file, i dont know how to initiate the project in git so i just upload the zip file. and thanks for your feed back, really appreciate

Comment: @MikkelNurfalah.i will look into it.give me some time

Comment: @MikkelNurfalah. unable to run since empty db.any way i have checked code. will popup close after submit or it wil lstay

Comment: oh yes i forgot, i just uploaded the db, you can download it in the same link. what do you mean about popup? i dont understand

Comment: @MikkelNurfalah.it works fine. i have added screenshot

Comment: i dont know whats going on but still not working for me, but somehow now i can get those id without ajax, i get it from request as an array, i fixed this by making unique name of each check-box. but the table doesnt updated, can you figure it out? i want to change the 'id_asisten' for each selected id which using whereIn i guess right?

Comment: you need to refrsh page

Comment: is it working on you? i refresh the page and the table doesnt updated as should be

Comment: table.ajax.reload();